# Power series with square summable coefficients

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

An exercise in my textbook asks to prove the following:

> Suppose $\sum |a_n|^2<\infty$. Show that the power series $\sum
>  a_nz^n$ has radius of convergence at least equal to $1$.

My reasoning is as follows:

Since $\sum |a_n|^2<\infty$ we should have $|a_n|^2\to 0$ and hence $|a_n|\to 0$.

Then $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}\le 1$ and hence the radius of convergence is at least one.

Although I believe my solution is correct, I still don't understand the reason for assuming square summability. We could have assumed that $\sum |a_n|^r<\infty$ for any $r>0$, couldn't we? Does $r=2$ have any particular application or significance?

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments are correct and you are correct that it would work for any $r > 0$. The main point is probably that square-summability is a weaker condition than (absolute) summability, yet still sufficient to guarantee the result. It might not be quite as obvious without Hadamard's formula.

Comment: Thanks David. I would still rather to see a statement which is more general and equivalently easy to prove. I think a better exercise would be perhaps: If $a_n\to 0$, then $\sum a_nz^n$ has radius of convergence at least equal to $1$.

Comment: Or just $|a_n|$ bounded.

Answer (score 0):

I think your conclusion $|a_n| \to 0 \implies \limsup |a_n|^{1/n} <1$ is not correct,  take e.g. $a_n = 1/n$. Then $a_n \to 0$ and $\lim a_n^{1/n} = 1$.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I meant $\le 1$. I fixed the typo.

Answer (score -1):

According to your  radius of convergence is at most one no